# Cookie detection code not working

Tags: php, cookies

Okay, I am building a members area section and I need to check if browser supports cookies. The index page will check if cookie exists and if it doesn't, will set a cookie and redirect to another page which will check for the set cookie and redirect back to index page if it finds the cookie else will display an error message asking the user to enable cookies. Please help i am getting "No cookie" message.

index.php

```
<?php
    if( !isset($_COOKIE['cookies_enabled']) ){
    setcookie( 'cookies_enabled', '', time() + 3600 * 24 * 365, '', '.example.com', 0, 1 );
    header("Location: http://www.example.com/members/login.php");
    exit;       
}else{
    $cookie_enabled = TRUE;
}
?>

<?php if( $cookie_enabled ) : ?>
    //do stuff
<?php endif; ?>
```

login.php

```
<?php
    if( isset($_COOKIE['cookies_enabled']) ){
    header("Location: http://www.example.com/members/");
    exit;
}else{
    $cookie_enabled = FALSE;
}
?>

<?php if( $cookie_enabled === FALSE ): ?>

    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <p>No cookie</p>

    </body>
    </html>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Is the cookie being set?

Comment: no, its not being set. Does browser need some time delay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is small mistake in setting the cookie value.

```
setcookie( 'cookies_enabled', 'COOKIE_VALUE', time() + 3600 * 24 * 365, '', '.example.com', 0, 1 );
```

Since you are checking whether the cookie is set or not, you need to specify the cookie value (I've set it as COOKIE_VALUE in the code). Add appropriate value for the cookie and then it should work.

I hope this helps.